# HTML5 Application Cache Manifest - index fallback without catchall

Tags: html, manifest, fallback, html5-appcache

I'm delivering a manifest for my app that looks something like this

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#1359542586541

NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
/ /index.offline
```

When offline, it works correctly by returning index.offline on the index path, however it has the side-effect of returning index.offline for every other resource as well. i.e. The `/` pattern is acting as a catchall.

Is there any way of matching the index page without everything else so ***only*** the homepage uses the fallback?

One irritation this causes is that it seems to return index.offline whenever a request returns a 500 status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first URL in a `FALLBACK` is a [prefix match](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#prefix-match).  The only way is to always use the explicit index page rather than rely on default documents:

```
FALLBACK:
/index.html /index.offline
```

There was a [discussion of the behaviour for 500 errors on HTML5 Help mailing list last February](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2012-February/000979.html) including several responses by the spec editor, [this message specifically talks about `FALLBACK` sections](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2012-February/000984.html).

Comment: thanks - but would that not require the user to explicitly request index.html?

Comment: @medovob That's why I said "always use the explicit index page".  You can always set up a server side redirect if you're worried about people typing in the wrong URL.

Comment: But the server-side redirect won't work offline unfortunately. This seems like a massive flaw in the spec. I think my solution will have to involve caching a simple html page for "/" with a client-side redirect.

Comment: @medovob Why would the server side redirect need to work offline?  In what situations are you expecting someone to access the wrong URL?

Comment: I would generally want users to be able to access the application offline directly using the domain name `http://mydomain.com` without them having to know to explicitly request `http://mydomain.com/index`

Comment: @medovob Yes, but are you expecting them to type that into the browser, or get it through a search result or a bookmark?  If you always redirect to `/index` then the bare domain should never appear in either place.

Comment: I see your point about about bookmarks and search results but I would still want to cover the common scenario where a user manually types in the URL.

Comment: @medovob I really think that's less common than you think it is; also the situation where it's actually important is the even less common scenario when they type in the URL when they're offline.  Also, most browsers will auto-complete the most commonly accessed URL at that domain.

Comment: you may be right - perhaps it is less common than I think but its still a very possible scenario and ignoring it is far from ideal. I'm really surprised that there's no obvious solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have implemented a cached client-side redirect at "/" for now - this redirects to "/index" which has the fallback to "/index.offline". Its not perfect but it does the job.